# How to map Azure Cosmos DB query recordset to C# class object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Customers container in an Azure Cosmos database. Following the standard data modeling advice to put customer-related data into the same container with partition key set to "/CustomerId", I have both customer's info and customer's sales order object in the container. The query SELECT * FROM c where c.CustomerId = 'CustomerABC' returns the following JSON object:

```
[
{
    "CustomerId": "CustomerABC",
    "type": "Customer",
    "name": "ABC",
    "location": "New York",
    "id": "fce01d24-2e5f-4738-af93-9ce251339015",
    "_rid": "XOQwAPL2q4QBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/XOQwAA==/colls/XOQwAPL2q4Q=/docs/XOQwAPL2q4QBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0500751f-0000-1e00-0000-60607a6e0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1616935534
},
{
    "OrderId": "Order1",
    "CustomerId": "CustomerABC",
    "Type": "Order",
    "Item": "Laptop",
    "Total": 500,
    "id": "3e8d7633-d2bf-4c0c-b494-632abc2cf44b",
    "_rid": "XOQwAPL2q4QDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/XOQwAA==/colls/XOQwAPL2q4Q=/docs/XOQwAPL2q4QDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"05009120-0000-1e00-0000-606085860000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1616938374
},
{
    "OrderId": "Order2",
    "CustomerId": "CustomerABC",
    "Type": "Order",
    "Item": "Battery",
    "Total": 125,
    "id": "7d759ff2-20f7-4c7a-9885-00d1a2f6faeb",
    "_rid": "XOQwAPL2q4QEAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/XOQwAA==/colls/XOQwAPL2q4Q=/docs/XOQwAPL2q4QEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"05009220-0000-1e00-0000-6060858e0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1616938382
}
```

]

This returned JSON contains an array or multiple items. I would assume the first item is always the customer info, but I am not 100% sure. It is followed by the sales orders by that same customer. My question is -- since they are not the same object type, how do you map this JSON to a C# class object where the c# class could be something like this:

```
public class CustomerOverview
{
    public CustomerInfo Info { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Do I just need to loop through each item in the JSON and check it's "type" property and then manually map  the item to my corresponding c# object? Or is there an easier way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Your “Order” item is missing “type” property. Is that intentional?

Comment: You are right Gaurav, I forgot to add type property for Order, fixed, thanks!

Comment: You could either deserialize based on the `type` value, or do two queries by different types and deserialize directly into the expected type for each result. For using dynamic, this answer has an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659628/2411713

Comment: Thanks so much Noah, learned a lot!

Comment: You could consider having a single document per customer, with the order information as a collection within that document. Structured similar to your `CustomerOverview` class. Then you wouldn't need a `Type` identifier, and wouldn't need to map the two by `CustomerId`

Comment: Thanks for the advice devNull. I do have other designs following this method, which I believed is called embedded. The difference between embedded and referenced is that embedded is typically just a few and don't grow too much. In my case, sales order could grow by the day to large number. Therefore, using referencing model is better I believe.